# How to get browser signer in Ethers.js 6?

Tags: ethers.js, ethsigner

I use Web3-Onboard to connect to Ethereum in a browser:

```typescript
const [{ wallet, connecting }, connect, disconnect] = useConnectWallet()
// ...
ethersProvider = new ethers.BrowserProvider(wallet.provider, 'any')
const signer = await ethersProvider.getSigner(); // Property 'getSigner' does not exist on type 'Provider'.
```

Why the error and how make this work?

Comment: The problem was that I assigned a wrong TypeScript type to `etherProvider` variable.